# Constructing a Free Body Diagram (Stacked Blocks)

Tags: statics

How can I construct the free body diagram of this figure? I am in a topic of equilibrium of particles so the total force will be equal to zero. The two springs are indicated to give equal forces.[image]

Am I correct that I need to add the masses of the blocks and then I will make an FBD together with two spring forces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is you need to isolate the masses from the environment. I.e. create a section.

[image]

At the points that section intersects with other objects (i.e. spring) you should place forces there with the correct direction.

Additionally you need to add any external forces like weight on the masses.

[image]